# Continuity of fields in Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage, singularities

I have a bunch of doubts in electrostatics.

1. In gauss law div(E)=rho/epsilon, is it implicitly assumed that the partial derivatives exist at every point in space?
2. Is it always true that a collection of charges produces a potential that is continuous and differentiable everywhere.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Dynamite. Welcome to Phys.SE. Do you know about the singularity in Coulomb's law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three basic possibilities for charge distributions:

1. if you look closely (like individual electrons, or small charged matter grains), then you will possibly describe the distribution by a set of point charges $$\rho(x)=\sum_i q_i \delta(x-x_i)$$ In this case the electric field will be defined and continuous everywhere except for the locations $x_i$ of the point charges. It is like punching out space at a countable set of points and solving Gauss' law ($\nabla \cdot E=\cdots\rho$) only on the "punched out space".
2. if you are more interested in the average charge distribution (like in a macroscopic charged conductor or insulator), then you will describe the distribution by a continuous (and real finite-valued) function $$\rho(x)\in {\bf R}$$ on a bounded spatial support region. In this case the resulting electric field will be defined and finite everywhere.
3. if you are interested in conductors or dielectrics, the charge distribution becomes infinite only on material surfaces, and you obtain expressions somehow similar to case (1.), but a little more mathematically elaborated. The rationale behind that is to describe surface charges. The resulting electric field will be discontinuous when crossing the surface. Cheap example: the Faraday cage, where you have an electric field outside a conductor, but zero electric field inside the conductor.

In any case, the electric field will be given (statically) by the volume integral
$$\vec E = k\int \rho(x) \frac{\vec x}{|x|^3} d^3 x$$
where $k$ is a boring constant that depends on the electrostatic unit system you have chosen (like something with $\epsilon_0$ and $4\pi$ and such).

In case of the point-charge distribution, you can integrate over the $\delta$-functions, in order to obtain the simpler form
$$\vec E = k\sum_i q_i \frac{\vec x_i}{|x_i|^3}$$

Something similar is possible for case (3.), where you obtain surface integrals of (area) charge distributions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how singular the spatial charge density is. If it is everywhere finite, then it is expected that partial derivatives of electric field exist everywhere and are finite.

If the charge density is somewhere infinite, then some partial derivatives of electric field at those points of space are not defined. This is the case if there is a charged surface, line or a point charge.